# From AJAX var to PHP variable getting the success code right

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have been working on this for a while and posted several related topics about it, but this is slightly different question. I have the following AJAX code with some html forms below it with in `#container` and `.myselect` is the class of a drop-down box. When I change the value in the box I want to be able to then use that value on other fields below the select. The AJAX code kinda works in that the alert shows the right value when changed but as you can see I have tried lots of `success` functions but no luck. The closest is
`$('#reloadtest').html(data);` which will show the value in my PHP and every time I change the value from then on it will change alot, but it reloads the page within the container.

Basically I want to know how I can reload the data but not the whole html/page so I can use the value of the drop down in my PHP.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#container').on( 'change', '.myselect', function() {                               
            var orderidVal = $(this).val();
            alert(orderidVal);
              $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       data: { orderidType : orderidVal },

                       success: function(data) {
                            //$('#container').reload('#container', function() {});
                            //$('#quoteselect').reload('#quoteselect', function() {});
                            //$('#container').load('orders.php #container', function() {});
                            //$('#quoteselect').load('orders.php #quoteselect', function() {});
                            //$('#testreload').reload('#testreload', function() {});
                            //location.href = "test2.php"
                            $('#reloadtest').html(data); //this allows me to use the variable but reloads the whole page within the page
                       }
            })
        });
      });
```

Comment: what exactly you want? be more specific...

Comment: could you be more specific? And more over.. could you post the related php code?

Comment: where is the URL you are calling using  AJAX ?

Comment: I think your script makes no difference between ajax-request and normal request, and in both cases return full html page. You should check if you have ajax/normal request and return data accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing an ajax-request you **have to** allocate an **URL** where to send the request.

If you don't Request anything jQuery reloads the page. As you can see [here in the jquery-api-docu](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the URL is the very first and most important parameter of the request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/url/to/the/php/script.php",
  success: function(data){
   //do something ... with data parameter
  }
});
```

would be the simple way of using ajax-request with javascript.

Comment: I need to use the value on the same page, is that not possible then?

Comment: well, yes I think it will work (just try it). but it is not recommended to mix up php and html, except for templating. so I'd recommend to put the php in an extra file.

Comment: I have sent the variable to anouther page where I set session to the value and in the sucess section reloaded the page so it will update that way. Have to figure out where to clear the session as to not avoid errors but thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

use two divs - one in which you can put ajax response and in other the remaining HTML code

Comment: How do you speerate ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

it reloads your page because you have not specified what page to request.
use the code below and replace /path/to/script to your actual script path

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').on( 'change', '.myselect', function() {                               
        var orderidVal = $(this).val();
        alert(orderidVal);
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,     
            type: "POST",
            url: '/path/to/script',
            data: { 'orderidType' : orderidVal },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#reloadtest').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed to send the variable to a page where I then set it to session and refreshed the main page, seems to work this way.